# objective-c parsing youtube video to see number of views

Tags: objective-c, parsing, youtube

I'm creating an app that constantly checks the number of views a youtube video has.

Is this possible? and how would I do it?

Example code, would be awesome :D

Thanks,
Elijah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start here with the client library

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

here are the sample applications

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/YouTubeSample

look here is sample code

http://pastebin.com/Bx6TCb2v

Comment: Do you mind showing a quick example on just how to fetch the amount of views on a video?

Comment: have you written anything yet? There is sample code in the link provided